# Chrome push notification - how to open URL adress after click?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification

I am new to Google Chrome Push notifications and I was just reading some questions and answers here, on stackoverflow and I have ended with this easy push notification javascript.

```
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');

function notify() {

    Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {

        if (result === 'granted') {
           navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {

                registration.showNotification('test notification', {
                    body: 'Hey I am test!',
                    icon: 'image.png',
                });

            });
        }
    });

}
```

Its just simple notification, but I need open a new window with other webpage after click on notification.

I know it is possible, but I cant find examples using "serviceWorker" syntax.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I am guessing you are in a Service Worker context, because that's where Push Notifications are received. So you have the `self` object to add a event listener to, that will react to a click on the notification.

(Place this code in your `sw.js` file, which is your Service Worker script.)

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    let url = 'https://example.com/some-path/';
    event.notification.close(); // Android needs explicit close.
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({type: 'window'}).then( windowClients => {
            // Check if there is already a window/tab open with the target URL
            for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                var client = windowClients[i];
                // If so, just focus it.
                if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                    return client.focus();
                }
            }
            // If not, then open the target URL in a new window/tab.
            if (clients.openWindow) {
                return clients.openWindow(url);
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: I needed this modification, clients.matchAll({ includeUncontrolled: true, type: 'window' }), to get it to work.

Comment: what is this mysterious undefined "clients" variable supposed to be

Comment: @stackers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients

Comment: where should I place this eventListener? In my fcm service worker or somewhere else? because I tried it in fcm sw and it didn't work for me

Comment: Works perfectly, @S.Aminnejad you can place this in firebase-messaging-sw.js

Comment: It wasn't working for me. Until I changed `matchAll({type: 'window'})` to `matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true})`. Also I search the host instead of the exact url.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to open website with dynamic URL received from FCM push notification or any other web push notification then

BELOW IS AN EXAMPLE OF SERVICE WORKER USED FOR FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {

    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  var notificationTitle = payload.data.title; //or payload.notification or whatever your payload is
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon,
    data: { url:payload.data.click_action }, //the url which we gonna use later
    actions: [{action: "open_url", title: "Read Now"}]
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

and handle click event with below code

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {

  switch(event.action){
    case 'open_url':
    clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url); //which we got from above
    break;
    case 'any_other_action':
    clients.openWindow("https://www.example.com");
    break;
  }
}
, false);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 10):

(This code refers to firebase messaging) I was also searching for a soluting and the answer was very easy, but there was no doc saying it clearly. You need to put "click_action" = "your url" inside the notification json. Here is an example:

```
notification: {
          title: "Come",
          icon: '../../../../assets/logo.png',
          vibrate: [300,100,400,100,400,100,400],
          body: "some text",
          click_action : "your link"
         }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The other answers did nothing.... clicking the notification didn't open anything. This answer works and is much simpler.

Comment: click_action is not a part of official browser Notification API. Above answer is for Firebase push notifications only.

Comment: There is no such option in official Notification API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification

Answer (score 0):

```
{

 "notification": {

   "title": "Hey there",

   "body": "Subscribe to might ghost hack youtube channel",

   "click_action" : "http://localhost:4200"

 },

 "to":"YOUR_TOKEN"

}
```

This worked for me

"@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",

```
"firebase": "^7.0 || ^8.0"
```