# chrome.notifications.onClosed not working in background.js for the google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm building a very basic google chrome extension that has to listen all received notifications comes through google chrome!

My Extension's file structure;

- manifest.json
- background.js
- icons

  - main.png

manifest.json

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {                   
          "16": "icons/main.png",          
          "24": "icons/main.png",           
          "32": "icons/main.png"            
        }
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "notifications"
      ]
}
```

background.js

```
console.log('Lady Gaga');

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
    console.log('Clicked');
});

chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function (s,b){
    console.log('notification Closed');
});

chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function (){
    console.log('notification Clicked');
});

chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function (){
    console.log('notification Button Clicked');
});
```

So if I click my extension's button

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked
```

Fired, and when I check the background LOGS, I can see that "Lady Gaga" and "Clicked" logs got fired!

Next, I'm trying to see logs of the notifications listeners. In order to fire up to notification's listeners found a website which has basic HTML buttons that sending notifications easily.

https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/

I'm using this website to send notifications on my own to test background event listeners which are defined as listeners for notifications events.

But none of the notifications events is not triggering, working properly. I can't see any logs like "notification Button Clicked" or "notification Closed"

What's wrong with that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name" : "demo1",
    "description" : "Demo",
    "version" : "0.1",
    "background" : { 
        "scripts" : ["background.js"],
        "persistent" : false
    },
    "permissions" : [
        "notifications"
    ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
var description = "dvcvv";
var news = "cvcvcvcvcvcvcvcvcv"; 
var pattern = {
    OPTION : "list",    
};

var a1 = {
    title : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    message : "dsdsdsdX"
};
var a2 = {
    title : "yyyyyyyyyyyy",
    message : "sdsdsdsdY"
};
var butt1 = {
    title : "Button 1 "
};
var butt2 = {
    title : "Button 2"
};

var notifopt = {
    type : pattern.OPTION,
    iconUrl : "icon.png",
    title : description,
    message : news,
    buttons : [butt1,butt2],
    items : [a1,a2]
};


chrome.notifications.create(notifopt,function() {
    console.log('Lady Gaga');
});

chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function() { 
    console.log('notification Clicked');

});
chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function() {
    console.log('notification Closed');
});
chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function() {
    console.log('notification Button Clicked');
});
```

**google chrome --> more tools --> extension --> load unpacked  --> refresh extension --> display notification --> click button1 --> click See the views page, in the background --> you see console.log**

Comment: How can I listen any other notifications which are not fired in extension?

Comment: You can use `navigator.serviceWorker` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418545/chrome-push-notification-how-to-open-url-adress-after-click

Comment: For example, producthunt sending me desktop notification  twice a day. This current code can handle this external desktop notifications?

Comment: I think that's what you want: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications

Comment: I have not found any more in the chrome.extension documentation

Comment: You have examples, samples there

Comment: I cannot handle desktop notifications which are incoming from any other website inside of a background process :(

Comment: I did not find anything about it in the documentation, books, pages. I do not know if it's possible